# How to get Yahoo user information using the user id (guid) in C#

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm using JY.Owin.Security.Yahoo to authenticate (since I had issues with the regular Oauth providers - it does not play nice with Google Oauth providers)

With JY.Owin - I'm only getting one field back - the Yahoo user id (guid)

I like to I get more info about the user like givenName, familyName, birthday, gender etc. (I know the email address is available)

**Is there a URL that I can use with GET or POST and add the yahoo user id to get more info?**

I'm trying to do this with C# but could not find any good examples yet...